# iframe modal click event on container

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

(I don't use jQuery)

I have an iframe on my website that looks like this

[image]

This modal closes when:
(1) clicking the close button at the upper right
(2) clicking outside of the content.

What I want to do is disable the (2).

Unfortunately, both the outside component and the content component don't have an id.

Is there any way I can achieve it?

Comment: Do you have any code you could share? Also a modal and an iframe are two different things. Do you mean that this modal loads in an iframe?

Comment: The iframe basically covers the entire screen, and in the modal exists in the iframe.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried handle container click event (on outside container) and stop it propagation?

```
$('iframe').contents().find('.container_div').on('click', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation;
});
```

or with vanilla Javacript:

```
var iframeInner= document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow;
var iframeInnerConatiner = iframeInner.querySelector(".container_div");

iframeInnerConatiner.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  e.stopPropagation;
});
```

Comment: Is there a solution that doesn't require jQuery? Ideally, bare Javascript touching HTML.

Comment: @Dave  Yes it's possible with Javascript too. I've add new code snippet in my answer.

Answer (score -2):

try this  $('#myModal').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false})